# How can I series fill dates in an org-mode table column

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do I fill a column with dates in org-mode and specify the period between them? I'm after being able to produce something along the lines of:

```
|Date      |Event  |
|----------+-------|  
|2014-03-10|Event 1|  
|2013-03-17|Event 2|  
|2013-03-21|Event 3|  
|and so on |       |
```

Comment: Is there any pattern in the dates you want to insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [tiny](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/tiny) package.

This snippet:

```
m\n7||%(date "2013-03-21" (* x 7))|Event %(1+ x)|
```

on <kbd>C-;</kbd> expands to:

```
|2013-03-21 Thu|Event 1|
|2013-03-28 Thu|Event 2|
|2013-04-04 Thu|Event 3|
|2013-04-11 Thu|Event 4|
|2013-04-18 Thu|Event 5|
|2013-04-25 Thu|Event 6|
|2013-05-02 Thu|Event 7|
|2013-05-09 Thu|Event 8|
```

It's more or less intuitive if you know Elisp - the snippet above is a shorthand for:

```lisp
(mapconcat
 (lambda(x)
   (let ((lst (list x)))
     (format "|%s|Event %s|"
             (tiny-date "2013-03-21" (* x 7))
             (1+ x))))
 (number-sequence 0 7)
 "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job perfectly for me. I was wondering whether there is a way using calc expressions in org-mode however.

Comment: You're welcome.
Here's what google shows about calc and org: http://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html.
I've heard good things about calc, but haven't used it much.
I have this idea of using J instead of calc to manipulate org tables, but I haven't gotten
to implementing it yet.